# How to run a 30 frame image sequence completely within Python/Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have 30 .gif images in a folder.  I'd like to create an image sequence that plays these images as a movie (24 or 30 fps) when prompted.  I also only want to use Python's internal libraries (no outside downloads).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I disagree with the hold.  The question is clear.  There is exactly one correct answer, not many, which I know upon reading the title and which TigerHawk already gave before the answer.  The answer, 'use `.after(milliseconds)`, is hardly too long even though TigerHawk chose to give a long version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to start this Answer with a warning: this feature is not for beginners, and it is almost certainly unnecessary for the project you're working on. I would recommend that you avoid this feature creep and simply make your program fulfill its purpose (enter the right code to open a safe). No one will mind in the slightest that the safe door doesn't animate to the open position. Of course, feel free to try it if you want to, but I ***very highly recommend*** finishing the basic functionality first. Then, if you want to add an animation as a sort of "part two" project, you'll at least have something working no matter how far you get with the animation (even professional programmers do this, so that Project X can meet the boss's new deadline even if Unnecessary Feature Y wasn't done yet).

I actually just implemented an animation function recently. I really wish there were a better system in `tkinter` or `pillow` or what have you for playing gifs, but this is the best I could come up with so far.

I used four methods (in my `tkinter` app):

- Choose the folder with the image sequence
- Choose framerate
- Start the animation
- Keep the animation running

The images should be of the form `'xyz_1.gif'`, `'xyz_2.gif'`, etc., with some characters (or nothing) followed by an underscore `_` followed by a dot `.` and an extension `gif`. The numbers must be between the last underscore and the last dot in the file name. My program uses `PIL`'s `Pillow` fork for its format compatibility and image manipulation features (I mostly just use `resize()` in this app), so you can ignore the extra steps that convert a `pillow` image into a `tkinter`-compatible image.

I've included all the methods relating to the animation for completeness, but you don't need to worry about most of it. The portions of interest are the `self.animating` flag in `start_animation()`, and the entire `animate()` method. The `animate()` method deserves explanation:

The first thing `animate()` does is reconfigure the background image to the next image in the `list` containing the image sequence. Next, it checks if animation is on. If it's off, it stops there. If it's on, the function makes a call to the parent/master/root widget's `after()` method, which basically tells `tkinter` "I don't want this done now, so just wait this many milliseconds and then do it." So it calls that, which then waits the specified number of milliseconds before calling `animate()` with the next number if possible or zero if we were at the end of the list (if you only want it to run once rather than looping, have a simple `if` statement that only calls `after()` if there's another image in the `list`). This is almost an example of a recursive call, but we're not calling the function itself from the function, we're just calling something that "puts it in the queue," so to speak. Such a function can proceed indefinitely without hitting Python's recursion limit.

```
def choose_animation(self):
    """
    Pops a choose so the user can select a folder containing their image sequence.
    """
    sequence_dir = filedialog.askdirectory() # ask for a directory for the image sequence
    if not sequence_dir: # if the user canceled,
        return # we're done
    files = os.listdir(sequence_dir) # get a list of files in the directory
    try:
        # make a list of tkinter images, sorted by the portion of the filenames between the last '_' and the last '.'.
        self.image_sequence = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(os.path.join(sequence_dir, filename)).resize(((self.screen_size),(self.screen_size))))
        for filename in sorted(os.listdir(sequence_dir), key=lambda x: int(x.rpartition('_')[2][:-len(x.rpartition('.')[2])-1]))]
        self.start_animation() # no error? start the animation
    except: # error? announce it
        if self.audio:
            messagebox.showerror(title='Error', message='Could not load animation.')
        else:
            self.status_message.config(text='Error: could not load animation.')

def choose_framerate(self):
    """
    Pops a chooser for the framerate.
    """
    framerate_window = Toplevel()
    framerate_window.focus_set()
    framerate_window.title("Framerate selection")
    try: # try to load an img for the window's icon (top left corner of title bar)
        framerate_window.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', framerate_window._w, ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("ico.png")))
    except: # if it fails
        pass # leave the user alone
    enter_field = Entry(framerate_window) # an Entry widget
    enter_field.grid(row=0, column=0) # grid it
    enter_field.focus_set() # and focus on it
    def set_to(*args):
        try:
            # use this framerate if it's a good value
            self.framerate = float(enter_field.get()) if 0.01 < float(enter_field.get()) <= 100 else [][0]
            framerate_window.destroy() # and close the window
        except:
            self.framerate = 10 # or just use 10
            framerate_window.destroy() # and close the window
    ok_button = Button(framerate_window, text='OK', command=set_to) # make a Button
    ok_button.grid(row=1, column=0) # grid it
    cancel_button = Button(framerate_window, text='Cancel', command=framerate_window.destroy) # cancel button
    cancel_button.grid(row=2, column=0) # grid it
    framerate_window.bind("<Return>", lambda *x: set_to()) # user can hit Return to accept the framerate
    framerate_window.bind("<Escape>", lambda *x: framerate_window.destroy()) # or Escape to cancel

def start_animation(self):
    """
    Starts the animation.
    """
    if not self.animating: # if animation is off
        try:
            self.animating = True # turn it on
            self.bg_img = self.image_sequence[0] # set self.bg_img to the first frame
            self.set_square_color('light', 'clear') # clear the light squares
            self.set_square_color('dark', 'clear') # clear the dark squares
            self.animate(0) # start the animation at the first frame
        except: # if something failed there,
            if self.audio: # they probably haven't set an animation. use messagebox,
                messagebox.showerror(title='Error', message='Animation not yet set.')
            else: # or a silent status_message update to announce the error.
                self.status_message.config(text='Error: animation not yet set.')
    else: # otherwise
        self.animating = False # turn it off

def animate(self, counter):
    """
    Animates the images in self.image_sequence.
    """
    self.board.itemconfig(self.bg_ref, image=self.image_sequence[counter]) # set the proper image to the passed element
    if self.animating: # if we're animating,
        # do it again with the next one
        self.parent.after(int(1000//self.framerate), lambda: self.animate(counter+1 if (counter+1)<len(self.image_sequence) else 0))
```

Comment: If the mistaken hold is lifted, I think this answer should be accepted.

Comment: Thanks again Tigerhawk - just now getting to try this out; really appreciate the help!